# Slabikar/WinEdt 9.0/Getting an error

Tags: errors, pdftex, latex-2.09

I'm getting the following error while compiling (note: I cannot find the missing file `slabik.cfg` in google.com)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{addfont}
    \addfont[1.5]{OT1}{slabikar}{\slabikar}
\begin{document}

\slabikar

OK, But it does not work.
\end

\end{document}
```

Command Line:

```
bibtex.exe "ideje3"
```

Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
> The top-level auxiliary file: ideje3.aux
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file ideje3.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ideje3.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ideje3.aux
> (There were 3 error messages)
> ```

Command Line:

```
texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\ideje3.tex"
```

Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
> entering extended mode
> (C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/TH0dipl/ideje3.tex
> LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
> Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\article.cls
> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty
> *************************************
> * Local config file bblopts.cfg used
> *
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg)
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\babel-czech\czech.ldf
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\babel\babel.def)))
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu)
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu)
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu))) (addfont.sty
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\oberdiek\twoopt.sty)
> (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty)) (ideje3.aux)Running miktex-makemf.exe...
> miktex-makemf: The slabikar source file could not be found.
>
> Running hbf2gf.exe...
>
>
> hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)
>
>
>
> Couldn't find `slabik.cfg'
>
> miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font slabikar.
>
> ! Font OT1/slabikar/m/n/10=slabikar at 15.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file n
> ot found.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.12 \slabikar
>
> ? 
>
> ! Emergency stop.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.12 \slabikar
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>
> Process has been killed ...
> ```

Comment: The font is not on ctan and in the texsystems. you need to get it from here http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/slabikar/.

Comment: I've visited that site, but I do not follow to which places should I copy all the particular files from petr.olsak.net :-(

Comment: put the tfm and the pfb in the folder of your document and add `\pdfmapline{slabikar  slabikar <slabikar.pfb} ` to the document.

Comment: To which line should I put \pdfmapline{slabikar slabikar <slabikar.pfb} ?

Comment: The characters are, however, somewhat modified: [see here](http://leteckaposta.cz/512666885)

Comment: The problem is that I use LaTeX while Olsak uses pdfcsplain ...I cannot configure my WinEdt 9.0 to use pdfcsplain.I do not know where to do it.

Comment: Sorry if you want to switch to csplain you are one your own, I'm not using it and I don't intend to spent time trying to figure out how it is done.

Comment: OK. If I want to generate a pdf file from "texify.exe" I can use this: --pdf "%F". What switches shall I use with latex.exe? The very same switches do not work.

Comment: if you want a pdf call pdflatex.

Comment: What switches should I give to pdflatex.exe to read the current file? texify.exe needs --pdf "%F".

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to call pdflatex. winedt has a build-in macro for it. My winedt uses (also for texify) `"%N%T"`, but my winedt is newer.

Comment: pdflatex.exe calls me for entering input filename from command line. It shows ** and waits till I enter the current filename and only then produces a pdf file.

Comment: Sorry but this comments are not meant for long debugging discussions. And if you have problem with the editor better ask on its mailing list - or update to a newer version.

Comment: I'm afraid of disnitegrating my WinEdt 9.0 enviroment which I use unregistered by deleting somethig from its register in Windows 8 for next 30 days.Where can I ask about my question, do you have some email address for me? Thank you.

Comment: winedt has a fine internet site where you can find all informations. Also be aware that I have absolutly no understanding for people not paying for the software they use. If you want a free editor use e.g. texstudio or one of the other free editors available.